# What is consuming memory in my Node JS application?

Tags: node.js, express

#### Background

I have a relatively simple node js application (essentially just expressjs + mongoose). It is currently running in production on an Ubuntu Server and serves about 20,000 page views per day.

Initially the application was running on a machine with 512 MB memory. Upon noticing that the server would essentially crash every so often I suspected that the application might be running out of memory, which was the case.

I have since moved the application to a server with 1 GB of memory. I have been monitoring the application and within a few minutes the application tends to reach about 200-250 MB of memory usage. Over longer periods of time (say 10+ hours) it seems that the amount keeps growing very slowly (I'm still investigating that).

I have been since been trying to figure out what is consuming the memory. I have been going through my code and have not found any obvious memory leaks (for example unclosed db connections and such).

#### Tests

I have implemented a handy heapdump function using `node-heapdump` and I have now enabled `--expore-gc` to be able to manually trigger garbage collection. From time to time I try triggering a manual GC to see what happens with the memory usage, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever.

I have also tried analysing heapdumps from time to time - but I'm not sure if what I'm seeing is normal or not. I do find it slightly suspicious that there is one entry with 93% of the retained size - but it just points to "builtins" (not really sure what the signifies).

[image]

Upon inspecting the 2nd highest retained size (Buffer) I can see that it links back to the same "builtins" via a setTimeout function in some Native Code. I suspect it is cache or https related (`_cache`, `slabBuffer`, `tls`).

[image]

#### Questions

- Does this look normal for a Node JS application?
- Is anyone able to draw any sort of conclusion from this?
- What exactly is "builtins" (does it refer to builtin js types)?

Comment: No idea, but it references `setTimeout`. Do the other "bultins" refer to the same method? It might be that you have some runaway timers which hold closure references…

Comment: I don't actually use any timers. It seems like the setTimeout call is inside the NativeModule - which seems to have something to do with HTTPS.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/11/nodejs-in-flames.html) 
TL;DR try switching to restify instead of express.